# getId3v1Tag() returns null

Tags: java, mp3

This is the method:

```
    public void createMp3Array() throws InvalidDataException, IOException, UnsupportedTagException {

    MusicFile song;
    String trackName;
    String artistName;
    String albumInfo = "";
    String genre = "";
    byte[] musicFileExtract;
    Mp3File mp3file;


    for (final File f : music.listFiles()) {
        ID3v1 tag;
        mp3file = new Mp3File(f.getAbsolutePath());
        tag  = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " " + tag);
        trackName = tag.getTitle();
        artistName = tag.getArtist();
        /*albumInfo = tag.getAlbum();
        System.out.println("info " + albumInfo);
        genre = tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")";
        System.out.println("genre " + genre);*/
        song = new MusicFile(trackName,artistName,albumInfo,genre);

        songs.add(song);
        System.out.println("wtf");
    }
}
```

The line **trackName = tag.getTitle();** returns gives me a NullPointerException every time except one. Everything works properly for the first mp3 file I tried, and it cannot work for any other.

Edit: I posted it accidentally without finishing editing my question sorry. The context is that I have to read a folder of mp3s and store their details in an array of MusicFile instances. There are two threads reading two seperate folders-I dont know if that has anything to do with it-. This is the error: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can we see the class `Mp3File`?

Comment: "gives me a NullPointerException every time except one". What do you mean by "except one"? If you could provide a little more info about that scenario, the community would be able to help better.

Comment: Mp3 class is imported, not a class I made. Also i came to the conclusion that by running the line tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag() on each mp3 I had in my folder, while i had like 130 songs, it did not return null for only 7 songs of them. So I guess the mp3 files have some problem. I cannot understand what.